# How can I get a postal order or cheque in British Pounds from outside of the UK?

Tags: uk, europe, money

Is there an online service where you can order valid cheques in pounds or a Royal Mail postal order from outside of the UK (more precisely in Belgium)?

I need a cheque or a postal order in pounds because the UK visas and immigration department lists these as the only acceptable forms of [payments for a freedom of information request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration).

Comment: As your in Belgium, does the post office there have international money orders?  It may not be online, but it might have the service you need.

Comment: I checked with Bpost (Belgian Post) and sadly they told me that they no longer offer any cheques :(.

Comment: You need to ask for money orders rather than cheques. They're not the same.

Comment: Ok, I will recheck with them about this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Most banks will provide cheques or money orders in foreign currencies for an appropriate fee, assuming you have an account with them. I have sent Sterling (GBP) cheques from my Canadian bank on many occasions. They would do it for most other currencies too.

[This service also appears to provide money orders in Belgium](http://moneygram.be/), with the option to receive GBP in the UK, although not online.

Comment: I have already tried that with my bank, I made them a request for cheques in pounds but they told me that they no longer such a service. I think that at least in Belgium banks want to phase-out cheques. That is why I was wondering whether there was an online service from where you could order cheques.

Comment: Did you ask about money orders and similar services?